# Should joke rejects be allowed?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I just sent in an edit to clean up some spit, as you all call it. In fact, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9412468)'s the link. Now, [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) and [Valery Viktorovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7226/valery-viktorovsky) has rejected it. tchrist said the image description isn't good. Is that a thing? Its something so small that can't even been seen. I feel that this is a joke. Also, how is it spam?

> [Valery Viktorovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7226/valery-viktorovsky) reviewed this 1 min ago: Reject
>
> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not promoting stack.imgur.com, or everyone will be banned

Comment: I believe people believed it's such a horrible question it should just be deleted. To be fair, your edit didn't improve the question at all, it's unsalvageable.

Comment: It was not a "joke reject", just a plain one.  They are trying to stop you from re-activating a very bad question, it does not deserve to be moved back onto everybody's front page.  Not after your edit either.  There is no official "should not reactivate the question" reject reason so they just pick something else.  Best to put your energy into salvageable posts.

Comment: You should avoid trying to polish turds. That question is completely unsalvageable and got quickly closed and deleted by the community. Suggesting edits like that on it wastes not only your time, but also the time of the reviewers.

Comment: I was one of the users that downvoted/flagged for closure. I wouldn't bother editing the question for them unless there's a damn good reason (i.e. that question I editied earlier that had a malware link). Like others have said but in a slightly different mannor: ***there's no point putting lipstick on a pig if you're about to butcher it anyway***

Answer (score 20):

Aside from wasting your time on a horrible question, your edit was invalid and deserved to be rejected:

- You introduced spelling errors.
- You uploaded an image to `stack.imgur.com` that you don't hold copyright to.